# Groupby operation from DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am confused for the following situations for using groupby. What is the difference between situation 1 and 2 ? I understand that DataFrame.groupby will return DataFrameGroupby object. But How does the situation 1 still remain in DataFrame type ?

1. data is DataFrame from pandas sql query by combing several tables

   ```
   data = pd.read_sql_query("....")
   ```

I group the data and drop the redundant "TheId" columns. In this way, the data is still in DataFrame type.

```
data_g = data.groupby('TheId', group_keys=True).apply(lambda x: x.drop('TheId', axis=1)).reset_index()
print(type(data_g))
```

This prints: `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

2. If I separated the operations, it became DataFrameGroupby type.

   ```
   data_g = data.groupby('TheId', group_keys=True)
   data_g.apply(lambda x: x.drop('TheId', axis=1)).reset_index()
   print(type(data_g))
   ```

This prints: `<class 'pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy'>`

I have tried to check pandas reference menu regarding groupby or groupby object but still can't find any clue about this.

Answer (score 0):

You did not assign the results of the operation you apply to `data_g` to a new dataframe. You only used `apply()` and `reset_index()` on a groupby and output the results to the console:

```
data_g = data.groupby('TheId', group_keys=True) 
data_g.apply(lambda x: x.drop('TheId', axis=1)).reset_index()
```

You need to assign the results of your operation to a new dataframe.

```
data_g  = data.groupby('TheId', group_keys=True) 
data_g2 = data_g.apply(lambda x: x.drop('TheId', axis=1)).reset_index() 

print(type(data_g2))
```

You should see `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`